# Opentok for android - Phonegap plugin

Tags: opentok

Is there any pointers available to start with Phone Gap and Android.??
I looked into Hello - World but thats Native and could not figure out heads or tails.
Tried searching for any step by step guide for android but couldnt find any..

My doubts (all related to Android)-

1. Any guide to help me connect between Android and OpenTok. i need documentationor something
2. Can i use Phone Gap plugin for Android ..or any other way to use Phone Gap with OpenTok for android..??

Your help is really appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here's a detailed answer for your question about phonegap on Android: [How to get opentok + flash running on phonegap despite lack of flash support for android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17533119/how-to-get-opentok-flash-running-on-phonegap-despite-lack-of-flash-support-for)

In short, no. There is no OpenTok PhoneGap plugin Android.

Regarding an Android OpenTok guide, it helps to know the [basics of how OpenTok](http://www.tokbox.com/blog/getting-started-with-opentok-from-0-to-simple-group-video-chat/). It follows the simple pub/sub model.

The reason why there is no detailed guides for OpenTok Android is because OpenTok Android is still very new in beta, and there will be many changes to come (some of them maybe breaking changes).