# How to get opentok + flash running on phonegap despite lack of flash support for android?

Tags: flash, cordova, opentok

Right, so we're trying to build a small 1-1 video demo on android tablets (Google Nexus Tablets). We're running into an issue, though, due to the fact that Flash doesn't seem to be supported at all. It doesn't come with the device, nor can we find it on the app store. After some research, we found a few hacks that could get it working - but we figured there must be some better way to get openTok + flash running on a phonegap app for android.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand this question correctly, you're trying to use the OpenTok Flash SDK in a PhoneGap project. Essentially, PhoneGap places a WebView and renders your HTML, CSS, and Javascript within the WebView to emulate a local app. However, as far as I know, Android no longer supports Flash in WebViews. So, your best bet is a PhoneGap OpenTok Plugin, which uses some native Android code to overlay a native Android view on top of your WebView to display the video streams. For example, there is an [iOS OpenTok PhoneGap Plugin](https://github.com/opentok/PhoneGap-Plugin) which does this same thing for iOS devices.

So, as far as I know, you have 2 options:

- You could build a native Android App using the  [OpenTok Android SDK](https://github.com/opentok/opentok-android-sdk).
- Or, you could build your own PhoneGap Plugin using the OpenTok Android SDK. Here's a [link](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/guide_plugin-development_android_index.md.html) that shows you how to build a PhoneGap Plugin for Android.